# syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, syntax-error

I can't seem to find where my code has went wrong. Here is my full error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\GigaLoad.com\register.php on line 102

But I've been looking a that line for hours. I will give you the entire code cause my newbie brain cant find the error:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'")
```

Hope you can help if you need more info just let me know.

Here Is The Extra Code

```
 if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") && (strlen($email) >=6)){
   require ("scripts/connect.php")
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") // <-- Error here
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($query)
   if ($numrows == 0){
        /* ... */
```

EDIT:

I am still getting major erros i will give the code and can you tell what i am missing

Comment: Can you give some of the surrounding code as well?  The error might be because of a typo on a previous line.

Comment: @templateypedef IPut The Extra Code Is That Enought

Comment: @CoryFournier You can edit your question. -_-

Comment: thanks @RiverC but i just go an error on the 103 line and i added the semi-colon

Comment: This fixed my error over a year later, idk why this was closed

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no semicolon at the end of that instruction causing the error.

EDIT

Like RiverC pointed out, there is no semicolon at the end of the previous line!

```
require ("scripts/connect.php")
```

EDIT

It seems you have no-semicolons whatsoever.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Comment: Or the line previous is missing a comma or semicolon.

Comment: Looks like missing semicolons.

Comment: And accidentaly (or not) the following line is also missing a semicolon. Hello Cory! PHP is not JavaScript! Semicolon is NOT optional.

Comment: kk well i am new to this so thanks i was following a tut and i got confused

Comment: Show error with line number php -d display_errors=1 -l foo.php

Answer (score 2):

If that is the entire line, it very well might be because you are missing a `;` at the end of the line.

Comment: Too bad the PHP parser won't just tell the OP that.